# How does the code in line 3 of the function work?

Tags: powershell

I came across the following code to upward (recurse) traverse XML node tree.

```
function Get-XPath($n) {
  if ( $n.GetType().Name -ne 'XmlDocument' ) {
    "{0}/{1}" -f (Get-XPath $n.ParentNode), $n.Name
  }
}
```

Would someone please explain in details how the code in line 3 works, one element (piece of code) at a time, ie. what does -f mean?

Comment: Read about the [Fomat Operator `-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f)

Comment: or here ;) https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-string-format/